# Opencart get common products from 2 categories

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

My problem is more with mysql than with Opencart. I want to retrieve from the database all products that belong to category_id1 and category_id2. Only those that belong in both categories. The model that get products from one category_id is this.

```
public function getProducts($data = array()) {
    $sql = "SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special";

    if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
        if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter pf ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)";
        }
    } else {
        $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p";
    }

    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";

    if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
        if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
            $sql .= " AND cp.path_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
        } else {
            $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
            $implode = array();

            $filters = explode(',', $data['filter_filter']);

            foreach ($filters as $filter_id) {
                $implode[] = (int)$filter_id;
            }

            $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";
        }
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_name']) || !empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
        $sql .= " AND (";

        if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
            $implode = array();

            $words = explode(' ', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data['filter_name'])));

            foreach ($words as $word) {
                $implode[] = "pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
            }

            if ($implode) {
                $sql .= " " . implode(" AND ", $implode) . "";
            }

            if (!empty($data['filter_description'])) {
                $sql .= " OR pd.description LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "%'";
            }
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_name']) && !empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
            $sql .= " OR ";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
            $sql .= "pd.tag LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_tag']) . "%'";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.sku) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.upc) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.ean) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.jan) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.isbn) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.mpn) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
        }

        $sql .= ")";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
        $sql .= " AND p.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";
    }

    $sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";

    $sort_data = array(
        'pd.name',
        'p.model',
        'p.quantity',
        'p.price',
        'rating',
        'p.sort_order',
        'p.date_added'
    );

    if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
        if ($data['sort'] == 'pd.name' || $data['sort'] == 'p.model') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY LCASE(" . $data['sort'] . ")";
        } elseif ($data['sort'] == 'p.price') {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
        }
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY p.sort_order";
    }

    if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
        $sql .= " DESC, LCASE(pd.name) DESC";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC";
    }

    if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
        if ($data['start'] < 0) {
            $data['start'] = 0;
        }

        if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
            $data['limit'] = 20;
        }

        $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
    }

    $product_data = array();

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
        $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
    }

    return $product_data;
}
```

I pass in the data array a second filter_category_id but how to use it? :D
I tried this simple code in phpmyadmin and got the results i want but i don't know have to use it in this model.

```
SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_product_to_category` WHERE `category_id` = x UNION SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_product_to_category` WHERE `category_id` = y
```

Another idea i had was to make two calls on the getProducts method, one for each category_id and after keep the common products. This can work but i think is bad in terms of performance.

I am sorry for the long post. Thank you in advance for any help.

George